# Schedule round robin matches

Tags: algorithm

How to implement a round robin schedule for an array of 4 elements `[1,2,3,4]`? The result of the algorithm should be able to display, for each element, the list of the players it will face in chronological order:

```
 (1: 4,2,3)
 (2: 3,1,4) 
 (3: 2,4,1) 
 (4: 1,3,2)
```

Line `1: 4,2,3` means that the player (1) will face in order the players (4), (2) and (3).

Of the same way, line `2: 3,1,4` indicates that the player (2) will face in order the players (3), (1) and (2).

We have implemented this code but we encounter a bug when we start filling in the name of the player. Do you have any idea about this problem?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define NAME_MAX_LENGTH 20
    #define NUM_MIN_PLAYERS 2
    #define NUM_MAX_PLAYERS 20

    enum Style
    {
        STYLE_COMPACT,
        STYLE_TABLE
    };

    enum Format
    {
        FORMAT_ID,
        FORMAT_NAME
    };

    struct PlayerList
    {
        unsigned int num_players;
        char name[NUM_MAX_PLAYERS][NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 1];
    };

    struct Grid
    {
        unsigned int num_players;
        unsigned int day[NUM_MAX_PLAYERS]
                        [NUM_MAX_PLAYERS];
    };

    void printList(struct PlayerList *list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list->num_players; i++)
        {
            printf("%d:%s\n", i + 1, list->name[i]);
        }
    }

    struct Grid calculer_berger(struct PlayerList *list)
    {

        struct Grid grid;
        // algo pour remplir la grid
        grid.num_players = list->num_players;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < list->num_players - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < list->num_players - 1; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    /* edge cases */
                    grid.day[i][list->num_players - 1] = ((i + j) + (i + j) / list->num_players) % list->num_players;
                    grid.day[list->num_players - 1][j] = ((i + j) + (i + j) / list->num_players) % list->num_players;
                    grid.day[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    grid.day[i][j] = ((i + j) + (i + j) / list->num_players) % list->num_players;
                }
            }
        }

        grid.day[0][list->num_players - 1] = list->num_players - 1;
        grid.day[list->num_players - 1][list->num_players - 1] = 0;
        grid.day[list->num_players - 1][0] = list->num_players - 1;
        return grid;
    }

    void permuter(struct Grid *grid)
    {
        int tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid->num_players; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= grid->num_players / 2; j++)
            {
                tmp = grid->day[i][j];
                grid->day[i][j] = grid->day[i][grid->num_players - j];
                grid->day[i][grid->num_players - j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    void print_grid(struct Grid *grid, struct PlayerList *list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid->num_players; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid->num_players; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    printf("%d:", grid->day[i][j] + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%d", grid->day[i][j] + 1);
                    if (j < grid->num_players - 1)
                    {
                        printf(",");
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {


        struct PlayerList playerList;
        char nom[NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 1];
        int nbCharLu = 0;

        while ((nbCharLu = fscanf(stdin, "%s", nom)) != -1)
        {
            strcpy(playerList.name[playerList.num_players], nom);
            playerList.num_players++;
        }

        struct Grid myGrid = calculer_berger(&playerList);

        printList(&playerList);

        print_grid(&myGrid, &playerList);
        printf("Apres la permut\n");

        permuter(&myGrid);
        print_grid(&myGrid, &playerList);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "round robin scheduling", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  This is a long-solved and well-covered problem.  We expect you to perform this research before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing the elements in an Integer array and that you would like to just display the results.
Here is one implementation....The code should accommodate "N" values because of the use of "sizeof"....

feel free to customize it further....

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
  int i,j;
  int array[] = {1,2,3,4};

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);++i){
    printf("(%d :",array[i]);
    for(j = 0; j < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);++j){
      if(j == i)   
        continue;
      printf("%d ",array[j]);
    }
    printf(")\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but the result of this code does not use the methodology of round robin with methodology Berger table.      the result must respect the order of confrontation between array element like this

Comment: (1: 4,2,3)
 (2: 3,1,4) 
 (3: 2,4,1) 
 (4: 1,3,2)

Comment: Taking a cue from the example provided in this [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm) on wikipedia, I have posted another response.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void main() {
  int mid;
  int num;
  int j, temp;
  int k = 0;
  int num1;

  int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};

  num = sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);
  mid  = (sizeof(data)/sizeof(int))/2;
  while(k < num - 1){
    printf("Round %d ( ",k+1);
    num1 = num;
    for(int i = 0;i < mid;i++,num1--) /*pairing the competitors in each round*/ 
      printf("%d:%d ",data[i],data[num1-1]);
    for(int i = 0,j = num-1; i < num -2;i++,j--){ /* fixing the first competitor and rotating the others clockwise*/
      temp = data[j];
      data[j] = data[j-1];
      data[j-1] = temp;
    }
    printf(")\n");
    k++;
  }

}
```